# SQL Query - how do filter by null or not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to filter a record....

If statusid is null, filter the record (where statusId is not null)

If statusid is not null, filter the record where statusid is equal to the specified statusid.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just like you said

```
select * from tbl where statusid is null
```

or

```
select * from tbl where statusid is not null
```

If your statusid is not null, then it will be selected just fine when you have an actual value, no need for any "if" logic if that is what you were thinking

```
select * from tbl where statusid = 123 -- the record(s) returned will not have null statusid
```

if you want to select where it is null or a value, try

```
select * from tbl where statusid = 123 or statusid is null
```

Comment: see my last addition that contains the "or"

Answer (score 4):

How about statusid = statusid.  Null is never equal to null.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE something IS NULL
```

and

```
WHERE something IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

set ansi_nulls off
go
select * from table t
inner join otherTable o on t.statusid = o.statusid
go
set ansi_nulls on
go

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
select * from tbl where statusid = isnull(@statusid,statusid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are trying to check NULL value of a column, you should use
 **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL**
You should not use *=NULL or ==NULL*

**Example**(NULL)

```
select * from user_registration where registered_time IS NULL
```

will return the rows with  `registered_time` value is `NULL`

**Example**(NOT NULL)

```
select * from user_registration where registered_time IS NOT NULL
```

will return the rows with  `registered_time` value is `NOT NULL`

**Note:** The keyword `null`, `not null` and `is` are `not case sensitive`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. `You should not use =NULL or ==NULL` ----> can you elaborate a little more on why this is a bad idea?